# Cognitive Service - Custom Speech C++

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to have a custom Speech to Intent in a *single* function call, that leverage custom acoustic and language model.

I am following the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/intent and aim to use continuous custom speech with LUIS intent.

As per the documentation, the function

```
SpeechFactory::FromSubscription
```

can either take LUIS subscription ID (available at luis.ai) in case of speech to intent detection 
or 
Custom Speech subscription ID (available after registration www.cris.ai) from speech.

There is a way to train custom speech with acoustic data model and custom language for higher accuracy training.

I have trained the speech subscription with custom language and acoustic data model and I would like to use these models *directly* for speech to intent recognition.

How do I do so?

So far, I have successfully used *either* custom speech with my acoustic and language model for STT *or* LUIS subscription ID for Speech to Intent recognition but unable to link my custom models for LUIS Speech to Intent.

I am using subscriptions from cris.ai and luis.ai. I am not interested in previous Bing STT SDK cause I need these custom acoustic model and language models for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no direct way to use both CRIS and LUIS using a single call (IntentRecognizer only supports base model). As workaround, you can call CRIS to get speech-to-text back, and then call LUIS to get intent.

Thanks,